# Selecting only duplicate rows, kinda

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm really not sure on the best way to explain this, but we have a database which has a unique ID for each employee, a description, and a flag for current.

```
SELECT COUNT("Current_Flag"),
  "Employee_Number"
FROM "Employment_History"
WHERE "Current_Flag" = 'Y'
GROUP BY "Employee_Number" ;
```

I'm trying to return the unique ID for every case where they have two current flags set, but I don't even know where to begin. I've tried a subselect which didn't work, I'm sure the answer is quite simple but I've just been told I only have 7 minutes to do it, so panicked and thought I'd ask here. Sorry all :/

Comment: You're going to need to post your current schema (i.e. what does the table look like!) before anyone can answer.

Comment: I need more info: besides ID and Current_Flag how do the records relate? Employee_Name?  is Employee_number the same in both cases? and they have different IDS?  (SAMPLE DATA!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a HAVING clause to your current query - like so:

```
select count("Current_Flag"), 
       "Employee_Number" 
from "Employment_History" 
where "Current_Flag" = 'Y' 
group by "Employee_Number"
having count("Current_Flag") >= 2
```

(Change the condition to `=2` if you only want *exactly* 2 matches.)

Comment: Lots of great replies and suggestions, thank you all very much - but just wanted to say I've tried this from Mark and it's working perfectly, thank you very much sir! (interestingly, my initial code above was actually right, there just aren't any duplicates! still a very useful exercise though) thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this (untested!). You might have to play around with HAVING/COUNT to get it to work

```
SELECT unique_id, description, flag FROM table GROUP BY unique_id HAVING COUNT(unique_id) > 1
```

Comment: I didn't downvote (I wish downvoters would leave explanations) but description and flag need to be aggregated / omitted in Oracle. Also, you need to restrict this to where current_flag is Y.

Comment: It's annoying! But that's a good point, I posted my answer before any schema/SQL was provided, which is why it's pretty vague.

Answer (score 0):

```
select employee_name, count(employee_name) as cnt 
group by employee_name
where cnt>1
```

I guess this will do the trick. Adapt it to the fields on your DB.

Comment: I didn't downvote (I wish downvoters would leave explanations) but you can't do a where clause on an aggregated value in the same query - this needs to be either a having clause, or you need to put the where clause in a main query and the rest of the query into a sub-query. Also, you need to restrict this to where current_flag is Y.

Answer (score 0):

Self Join table return only rows where 2 "Flags" are alike exclude rows that match on UniqueID returning al instances of ID having matches on flags.

```
Select A.ID
from table A
INNER JOIN table B 
on A.Flag1=B.Flag1 and A.Flag2=B.Flag2
Where A.ID <> B.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

(UNTESTED STATEMENT)

```
SELECT Id FROM TABLE1 T1 WHERE T1.Id NOT IN(
SELECT Id FROM TABLE2 T2 WHERE (T1.Flag1 = T2.Flag1) AND (T1.Id <> T2.Id))
```